# Magento2 (pre-alpha) theme not showing in Admin

Tags: magento2, theme

I created my own theme based on the blank theme but I can not get it to show in Admin

```
<design>
    <package code="default">
        <title>Default</title>
        <theme version="2.0.0.0" code="brent" parent="demo" featured="1">
            <title>Brent Super Theme</title>
            <requirements>
                <magento_version from="2.0.0.0-dev1" to="*"/>
            </requirements>
            <media>
                <preview_image>media/preview_image.jpg</preview_image>
            </media>
        </theme>
    </package>
</design>
```

I did also find the themes in the database

```
SELECT * FROM core_theme
```

and I did a test by removing the blank theme and now it doesn't show in admin!

Do I need to setup some sort of initialization?
[image]

Comment: Are you using version `2.0.0.0-dev46` yet?  It makes another significant change to theme organisation.

Comment: no I have dev45, I just upgraded, now I have to upgrade my Zend Server to 5.4 :(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the pre-alpha/unreleased Magento 2.0 product deemed OT by this meta thread: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79/are-magento-2-0-questions-allowed

Comment: I've added my $0.02 on that meta thread. I'd rather cut over sooner than later, and plenty of the Magento heavy hitters are already working with the pre-alpha. I suggest aggressive enforcement/provision of tags to solve the problem of future context.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a pre-alpha version of Magento 2 and no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined your theme but it doesn't look like you made it active.

Comment: Mark I found a post to activate, but I don't find my link in admin? System -> design -> theme activate?